# html2canvas and jsPDF generates pdf little bit blurry

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf-generation, jspdf

I am generating html pages with Google chart by domtoimage and jsPDF library. But its generated PDF document looks little bit blurry on Acrobat Reader and fine on Google Chrome. I've tried to printing it and result was so blurry. How to increase quality of PDF?

Code that generates PDF:

```
function makePDF(a, fname){
    var key;
    var doc = new jsPDF('l', 'mm', 'a5', true);
    for(key in a){
        doc.addImage(a[key],'PNG',0,0*key,210,148);
        if(a.length - 1 === key*1){
        }else{
            doc.addPage();
        }
    }
    doc.save(fname + ".pdf");
    $(".www").css("margin","auto");
    a = null;
    isdone = true;
    ngViewLoader(false);
}
```

Code that converts DOM Element to image:

```
function build_image(dis){
    domtoimage.toPng(dis).then(function(dataUrl){
        a.push(dataUrl);
        arr_index++;
        if(index === a.length){
            makePDF(a, fname);
        }else{
            if(arr_index > 13){
                return false;
            }
            build_image(arr_dis[arr_index]);
        }
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.error('oops, something went wrong!', error);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Rozig

Try using the following code below instead:

`domtoimage.toJpeg(dis, {
    quality: 1.0
})`

The JPEG full quality is better compared to the PNG output. But depending on how big your image is being rendered, it still won't be completely look sharp.